# Cant download on iOS with expo-file-system

Tags: ios, typescript, react-native, expo

Im trying to download using Expo-File-System on an expo project with react native.

The download option works on Expo-Go during testing but wont work when i push it in production mode.

It says that it is "unable to save file in the local URI because you dont have Document Permissions" as shown in the Picture below.

Here is the code (Using typescript):

```
import * as MediaLibrary from 'expo-media-library';

///For downloading the file
  const download = async (item: ICurriculumCourseDocument) => {
    setIsloading(true)

    await FileSystem.downloadAsync(
      `https:/baseUrl`,
      FileSystem.documentDirectory + item.filename,
      options
    )
      .then(({ uri }) => {
        setIsloading(false)
        console.log('Finished downloading to', uri);
        onShareIOS(uri)
      })
      .catch(error => {
        setIsloading(false)
        alert(error);
      });
  }


//For sharing the file using the Share
  const onShareIOS = async (uri: string) => {
    const imageFileExts = ['jpg', 'png', 'gif', 'heic', 'webp', 'bmp'];

    if (imageFileExts.every(x => !uri.endsWith(x))) {
      const UTI = 'public.item';
      await Sharing.shareAsync(uri, {UTI});
    }  
  };
```

Here is the full Alert with the error message:
[image]

Comment: The library should tell you which permissions you need to put into Info.plist, have you added everything you need to there?

Comment: @Abe the Library shows these two premissions for the expo file system, both are in it: "NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription":"", "NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription":""

Comment: You have to add an explanation to the permission, or else it won't be granted.

Comment: Like what? Is there something specific you have to add? Or just some string with a simple explonation

Comment: Yes, a string with a simple explanation

Comment: @Abe Still get the same result